# tcl : compare 2 file with diff and grep the output

Tags: grep, tcl, diff

I would like to compare 2 file and show the difference between files

when I use the following :

```
exec sh -c "diff -w file1 file2 \|grep \<"
```

but no result is shown and the script is brokeen

what's wrong with the tcl command ?

Comment: What is the < at the end of the line supposed to do?  Try running your command in a shell first and make sure it works.

Comment: Oh, you're having backslash issues.  The backslash gets eaten by tcl, so you have to double it:  `...grep \\<`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will work:

```
puts [exec sh -c "diff -w file1 file2 |grep \\<"]
```

The < needs to be double-backslashed, and the output should be printed.